# Iterate through Dictionarys values

Tags: c#, dictionary, yaml

Hey i am deserializing a yaml file and (i dont know the structure before i run the program) into a `Dictionary<object, List<object>>` how can i iterate through this object and the values. This is what i have tried. Or do you have another idea to get the values of a yaml file without knowing the structure thanks

```
var t = deserializer.ParseYamlTagByType(text);

foreach (KeyValuePair<object, List<object>> entry in t)
{
    foreach (Dictionary<object, object> item in entry.Value)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> tag in item)
        {
            //List<object> value = (List<object>)tag.Value;
            foreach (var config in (List<object>)tag.Value)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> test = (Dictionary<object, object>)config;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> configurationString in test)
                {
                    var tagname = configurationString.Key;
                    var tagvalue = configurationString.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public Dictionary<object, List<object>> ParseYamlTagByType(string input)
{
    return this.deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<object, List<object>>>(input);
}

public class CalcYamlFile
{
   [YamlMember(Alias = "gc", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
   public List<CalcTag> GcTag { get; set; }
}

public class CalcTag
{
   public Clean Clean { get; set; }
   public Dependencies Dependencies { get; set; }
   public Solution Solution { get; set; }
   public Test Test { get; set; }
}

public class Clean
{
  [Required]
  public object Location { get; set; }
  //Maybe something for the value of the location tag
  public object Pattern { get; set; }
  public object Continue { get; set; }
}
```

```
gc:
  - clean:
      - location: build/buildresults/
        pattern: '*'
      - location: build/testresults/
        pattern: '*'
    dependencies:
      location: blah
  - solution:
      results: build/buildresults/
    test:
      configuration: Release
      results: build/testresults/Release/windows/
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are experiencing? Does your code work but you want to make it more general or it doesn't work? I would say that you are ignoring the info in the keys of the dictionary. What final structure do you want or what is the info you want to retrieve?

Comment: the code works till theres only one item in a value then it will crash on the line
foreach(var config in (list<object>tag.value))
and yes maybe you can make it more general or you know an better way to iterate through a dictionary

Comment: Feels like you're going to need something recursive if you don't know the structure/the deserializer makes Dictionaries of Dictionaries (of Dictionaries)

Comment: Maybe you can add a code sample or something please

Comment: It would be easier to help if you tell us what you are trying to achive? (do you want to collect the final tags in the tree?, do you want to transform this dictionaries structure into your custom objects structures? do you want to find a specific tag?)

Comment: i have added a possible yaml file
1. i want to get the values and if its a path i need to check if it exists
2. i want to check if the tags are correct spelled
for that maybe its the best way to have a structure like a list named gc containing 4 list clean dependencies test solution
the reason why i deserialize it firstly to dictionary is because i dont know the structure and in this example i will get two list one containing clean and dependencies and one containing solution and test because of the - infront of the tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, make sure that there isn't any libraries that do that for you already (Json, etc.).

If you want to program it yourself, provided that all the items in your enumerations are `object`, this may work for you:

```
lang-cs

public static void GetTagsRecursive1(ref List<Tuple<string, string>> addedTags,string keyName, object tagsSource)
{
    if (addedTags == null)
        addedTags = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    if (tagsSource == null)
        return;

    string rootName = keyName != null ? keyName + " >> " : "";

    if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object,object>)
    {      
        foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>))
        {
            if (elem.Value is IEnumerable && !(elem.Value is string))
                GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value);
            else
                addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
    else if (tagsSource is List<object>)
    {
        foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as List<object>))
        {
            if (elem is IEnumerable && !(elem is string))
                GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, keyName, elem);
            else
                addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, elem.ToString()));
        }
    }
    else
        addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, tagsSource.ToString()));
}
```

and would be called as:

lang-cs
var t = deserializer.ParseYamlTagByType(text);
List<Tuple<string, string>> addedTags = null;
GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, null, t);

This would give you something like:

```
Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/buildresults/
Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/testresults/
Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
Gc >> dependencies >> location  >>  blah
Gc >> solution >> results  >>  build/buildresults/
Gc >> test >> configuration  >>  Release
Gc >> test >> results  >>  build/testresults/Release/windows/
```

**EDIT ---------------------------------**

In case not all of your types are `object`, I came up with a solution using a bit of Reflection. It may not be the most efficient way to do it, though:

```
lang-cs
public static void GetTagsRecursive(ref List<Tuple<string, string>> addedTags, string keyName, object tagsSource)
{
    if (addedTags == null)
        addedTags = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    if (tagsSource == null)
        return;

    string rootName = keyName != null ? keyName + " >> " : "";

    if (tagsSource is IEnumerable && !(tagsSource is string))
    {
        IEnumerable myEnumerable = (IEnumerable)tagsSource;

        if (IsDictionary(tagsSource))
        {
            bool PropInfoInit= false;
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo KeyPropInfo = null, ValuePropInfo = null;
            foreach (var elem in myEnumerable)
            {
                if (!PropInfoInit)
                {
                    Type KeyPairType = elem.GetType();
                    KeyPropInfo = KeyPairType.GetProperty("Key");
                    ValuePropInfo = KeyPairType.GetProperty("Value");
                    PropInfoInit= false;
                }
                object key = KeyPropInfo.GetValue(elem);
                object val = ValuePropInfo.GetValue(elem);                           

                if (val is IEnumerable && !(val is string))
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, rootName + key, val);
                else
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(rootName + key, val.ToString()));
            }
        }
        else if (IsList(tagsSource))
        {
            foreach (var elem in myEnumerable)
            {
                if (elem is IEnumerable && !(elem is string))
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, keyName, elem);
                else
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, elem.ToString()));
            }
        }
        else
                throw new Exception("Unexpected Type: " + tagsSource.GetType());                   

    }
    else
        addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, tagsSource.ToString()));
}

static bool IsDictionary(object obj)
{
    return obj is System.Collections.IDictionary &&
            obj.GetType().IsGenericType &&
            obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Dictionary<,>));
}

static bool IsList(object obj)
{
    return obj is IList &&
            obj.GetType().IsGenericType &&
            obj.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));
}
```

**EDIT 2 ----------------------------------**

Based on @theiliii comments, assuming that you want to convert your yaml file into a very fixed structure of objects, the code could look something like this:

```
lang-cs
public class CalcYamlFile
{
    const string gcTag = "gc";
    public CalcTag Gc { get; set; } = null;

    public CalcYamlFile(string text)
    {
        var t = deserializer.ParseYamlTagByType(text);

        if (t is Dictionary<object, object>)
        {
            Dictionary<object, object> tdict = t as Dictionary<object, object>;

            object calcTagSource;
            if (tdict.TryGetValue(gcTag, out calcTagSource))
                Gc = new CalcTag(calcTagSource);
            else
                Trace.WriteLine("GC tag not found");
        }
    }      
}

public class CalcTag
{
    const string cleanTag = "clean";
    const string dependenciesTag = "dependencies";
    const string solutionTag = "solution";
    const string testTag = "test";
    public Clean Clean { get; set; } = null;
    public Dependencies Dependencies { get; set; } = null;
    public Solution Solution { get; set; } = null;
    public Test Test { get; set; } = null;


    public CalcTag(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
                AddTagObjects(tagsSource);
            else if (tagsSource is List<object>)
            {
                foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as List<object>))
                {
                    if (elem is IEnumerable && !(elem is string))
                        AddTagObjects(elem);
                    else
                        Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected element in CalcTag list");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddTagObjects(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
            {
                foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>))
                {
                    switch(elem.Key.ToString())
                    {
                        case cleanTag:
                            if (Clean == null) Clean = new Clean(elem.Value);
                            else Trace.WriteLine($"{cleanTag} Tag already exists");
                            break;
                        case dependenciesTag:
                            if (Dependencies == null) Dependencies = new Dependencies(elem.Value);
                            else Trace.WriteLine($"{dependenciesTag} Tag already exists");
                            break;
                        case solutionTag:
                            if (Solution == null) Solution = new Solution(elem.Value);
                            else Trace.WriteLine($"{solutionTag} Tag already exists");
                            break;
                        case testTag:
                            if (Test == null) Test = new Test(elem.Value);
                            else Trace.WriteLine($"{testTag} Tag already exists");
                            break;
                        default:   Trace.WriteLine($"Unexpected Tag in CalcTag"); break;

                    }
                }
            }
            else   Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected tagsSource type");
        }
        else Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected null tagsSource");
    }
}

public class Clean
{
    const string patternTag = "pattern";
    const string locationTag = "location";
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> LocationPatternPairs { get; set; } = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
           
    public Clean(object tagsSource)
    {
        LoadTagsRecursive(tagsSource);
    }
    private void LoadTagsRecursive(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> tagsSouceDict = tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>;

                if (tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(locationTag) && tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(patternTag))
                {
                    if (tagsSouceDict.Count > 2)
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Clean source  contains more items than {patternTag} and {locationTag}");

                    LocationPatternPairs.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(tagsSouceDict[locationTag].ToString(), tagsSouceDict[patternTag].ToString()));
                }
                else   Trace.WriteLine($"Clean source does not contain {patternTag} or {locationTag}");
            }
            else if (tagsSource is List<object>)
            {
                foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as List<object>))
                {
                    if (elem is IEnumerable && !(elem is string))
                        LoadTagsRecursive(elem);
                    else
                        Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected element in Clean list");
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}


public class Dependencies
{
    const string locationTag = "location";
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public Dependencies(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> tagsSouceDict = tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>;

                if (tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(locationTag))
                {
                    if (tagsSouceDict.Count > 1)
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Dependencies source  contains more items than {locationTag}");

                    Location = tagsSouceDict[locationTag].ToString();
                }
                else Trace.WriteLine($"Dependencies source does not contain {locationTag}");
            }
            else Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected Dependencies source type");
        }
        else Trace.WriteLine("Dependencies source is null");
    }
}

public class Solution
{
    const string resultsTag = "results";
    public object Results { get; set; }

    public Solution(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> tagsSouceDict = tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>;

                if (tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(resultsTag))
                {
                    if (tagsSouceDict.Count > 1)
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Solution source  contains more items than {resultsTag}");

                    Results = tagsSouceDict[resultsTag].ToString();
                }
                else  Trace.WriteLine($"Solution source does not contain {resultsTag}");
            }
            else  Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected Solution source type");
        }
        else Trace.WriteLine("Solution source is null");
    }

}

public class Test
{
    const string ConfigurationTag = "configuration";
    const string resultsTag = "results";
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }

    public Test(object tagsSource)
    {
        if (tagsSource != null)
        {
            if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
            {
                Dictionary<object, object> tagsSouceDict = tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>;

                if (tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(resultsTag))      
                    Results = tagsSouceDict[resultsTag].ToString();
                else Trace.WriteLine($"Test source does not contain {resultsTag}");

                if (tagsSouceDict.ContainsKey(ConfigurationTag))
                    Configuration = tagsSouceDict[ConfigurationTag].ToString();
                else Trace.WriteLine($"Test source does not contain {ConfigurationTag}");

                if (tagsSouceDict.Count > 2)
                    Trace.WriteLine($"Test source  contains more items than {resultsTag} and {ConfigurationTag}");
            }
            else Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected Test source type");
        }
        else Trace.WriteLine("Test source is null");
    }
}
```

But beware that this is not flexible at all. It will only work if the structure in your yaml file is a faithful reflection of your classes structure and vice-versa

Comment: Thanks i have added 3 classes to my question. Is it possible to add the list of tupel to this structure i need to check if the words are correct spelled and some tag are required. For the value of the location for example. it would be great that it looks same as the tuple with the two items one for the tag and one for the value

Comment: @theiliii: This is a different way of doing it. By your classes it seems that your structure is fixed so you don't need a general recursive method but something that actually searchs for specific tags to create your classes structure. It could be recursive but analysing in each level the key of the dictionary to match it to any of your classes. Give it a try, post you attempt and we'll try to help you

Comment: Can u help me to get the list to my custome class structre i have no idea how to do that the fastest way thanks

Comment: @theiliii, usually you post your attempt and we try to help you. It would be a massive amount of work to try to figure out what you want exactly and then do it for you. Please, update your answer with the best code you have to far and specify more precisely the structure of your lists/dictionaries to clearly state what is a dictionary and what is a list

Comment: Do you have an idea how it would be easier to add the string list to my custom class structure.

Comment: Is it possible to create objects of my classes in your function so that i have the same structure like the List<tuple<string,string>> but with my custome objects

Comment: yeah in the end i should have a simple program which can deserialize a yamlFile with an unknown structure but i know which tags can be present. So a clean must contain a location. Is that something i can achieve with your code? Thanks for your work

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you that I have added a second edit part to my answer. Have a look at it and check if it fits for you.